# Does apache apply directives sequentially?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I am fresh new with apache and I could not easily google the answer.

Will same directive found further inside httpd.conf override the former? For example:

```
Timeout 400
Timeout 500
```

Is resultant timeout 500?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on a directive. For example you can use several `Listen` directives and Apache will listen on every defined port. But if you use several `StartServers` directives only the last will apply (I just checked that on my setup). I guess default behaviour is to apply the last directive (and `Listen` is one of exceptions to that rule) so the timeout will be 500.

Comment: How to know is a directive that appears multiple times will be overridden or appended to teh previous value? For example I want to know for `RequestReadTimeout`?